# Parsing a string in Hive

Tags: sql, hive, hiveql

I've been using the split_part function in Redshift and am looking for the equivalent in Hive. I want to parse urls in the below format. I've looked at the parse_url function and don't think there is an option for what I need. So I think I need some string function.

so for the below urls:

```
www.ibm.com
www.fr.ibm.com
```

I want everything after the www. The documentation has a substring_index function which seems like what I need but it doesn't work on the version of Hive I'm using (not sure how to check the version i'm on)

Comment: Why not just take everything after the 4th character or after the first occurrence of a period?

Comment: You can use regexp_replace if you always want to replace www

Comment: @GordonLinoff sometimes there is http so the character position is not always reliable.

Comment: @Moosa . . . You should better explain what you really want to do in the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use `REGEXP_EXTRACT()` and grab everything after the first `.`

```
SELECT url
  , REGEXP_EXTRACT(url, '\\.(.*)') AS parsed_url
FROM db.tbl
```